# Add sql database in mfc dialog based application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a MFC dialog based project,Now I want to add database with that project.
I have no idea how to do this.
can anybody provide the useful link?

Actually when I create a new dialog based MFC project, the database support is hide.
So I want to ask that

**MFC dialog base project support database or not**

When I create new Dialog based MFC project

[image]

Database support is hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better directly use `CDatabase` and `CRecordset` classes to open to the database, and read/write to the tables, or call SQL using different `CRecordset` objects.

You need only one `CDatabase` object, and attach it to different `CRecordset` instances (**one** at a time). You may directly use `CRecordset` and use `GetFieldValue` method in a loop (controlled by `IsEOF` method). Or you may inherit from `CRecordset` and implement `DoFieldExchange`. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxt1e3z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The database support in appwizard is ment for doc/view architecture. It will quickly help you to create ODBC classes.

Definitely you can use database in MFC applications. you can use ODBC/ADO to connect to the database and access it.  You can refer these sites

1. http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Visual_C_PlusPlus&seqNum=190
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk4h509a(VS.80).aspx
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2c4cthk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thnx for the help but look at the question,I have edited this.