# Adding SqlServer Database to MFC dialog based application

Tags: c++, sql-server, mfc, dialogbasedapp

I have some code in c# that can connect to a sqlserver database and display the data on a datagridview:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\UVSS\\Documents\\CommPortDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
conn.Open();            
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from UVSSTable1", conn);
var table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

How do I use the same in an MFC dialog based application in c++? I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360247/add-sql-database-in-mfc-dialog-based-application) previous question, but it doesn't seem to cover what I need to know.

Comment: Sample code probably won't help (much). You *mostly* generate code like this with the AppWizard (and such), so you really want the know about the steps to follow to generate it, now the code itself.

Comment: First, you have to realize there are two rather different ways to display data from a database. The question you linked is using MFC's CDatabase and such. The code you're showing in C# seems to be using a datagrid control. You can do either in MFC, but the methods and code will be substantially different between the two.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can you please provide a link that can take me through the steps; or maybe an example application to start with. I am open to use any method as long as i am able to display the data on a table.

Comment: [One possibility](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1884/MFC-DataGrid).